# How to get all value from element using Jquery and put it to an Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i got an html looking like this

```
<a href="1" class="link">
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="A"></div>
 </div>
</a>
<a href="2" class="link">
 <div class="div1">
  <div></div>
 </div>
</a>
<a href="3" class="link">
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="C"></div>
 </div>
</a>
```

and i want to get the second div tag and put it to an Array so it become like this

```
arr = [A,0,C]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with jQuery's [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

```js
var arr = $('.div1 > div').map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('class') == undefined? 0 : $(this).attr('class');
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="1" class="link">
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="A"></div>
 </div>
</a>
<a href="2" class="link">
 <div class="div1">
  <div></div>
 </div>
</a>
<a href="3" class="link">
 <div class="div1">
  <div class="C"></div>
 </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

targets div tag(has class "div1") by selector and find inner div
and check if it has class or not like this.

```
var array;
$(".div1").each(function(index, item){
   var className = $(this).find("div").attr("class");
   if(!className){ array.push("0") }
   else {array.push(className)}
});
```

Comment: No need for `find`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = [];
 $('.div1').each(function(i, obj) {
     var value = $(this).find('div').attr("class");
     if (typeof value === "undefined") {
            value = 0;
     } 
     arr.push(value); 
});

  alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Added demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Rakesh029/460c5tLv/1/

Comment: No need for `find`

Comment: @mplungjan There may be different ways to do any task. There is not any specific note mentioned in question that we don't need to use 'find'.

Comment: That is correct. There is also no note saying we have to be succinct and use the most direct path to the data... So don't mind me. Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner

```js
let arr = [...document.querySelectorAll(".link>.div1>div")].map(div => div.className || "0")

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<a href="1" class="link">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="A"></div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="2" class="link">
  <div class="div1">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="3" class="link">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="C"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```